# How to remove number in ng-grid header when using sortInfo in angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I am beginner with angularjs. I have ng-grid with default sorting by 3 columns defined:

```
sortInfo:{
    fields: ['Col1', 'Col7', 'Col6'], directions: ['desc', 'desc', 'asc']
  },
```

but in result I'm getting small labels in grid header:

[image: Grid header row]

How can I get rid of these number?

I tried using custom template for header and removing sortPriority part, but it didn't work. Is it sortPriority at all or am I looking at wrong place?

Comment: use ui-grid instead of ng-grid if you are starting new

Comment: What numbers do you mean? The little ones? Thy must come from your custom template. Show us the code of said template please. Or even better a Plunker/fiddle with all of your code and css.